# How to calculate the trajectory of an object with an initial velocity so that it stops at a given point

Tags: algorithm

The subject comes from an old challenge on [codingame.com](http://codingame.com).

The play area was a rectangle of **10000** x **8000** units.

I have an object with a position (**objectX**, **objectY**) and a velocity vector (**speedX**, **speedY**).
I have an object with a position (**objectX**, **objectY**) and a velocity vector (**speedX**, **speedY**).

To move this object, I have to display the coordinates (**thrustX**, **thrustY**) of the thrust destination followed by a thrust value (ranging from **-100** to **100**).

Friction: Each steps (ticks), previous speed vector is multiplied by 0.9 before applying thrust

I want to move and stop this objet at a point with coordinates **targetX**, **targetY** (with a given error rate).

How to calculate the list of **targetX**, **targetY** and **thrustValue** ?

Following example use these data:

- initial objectX and objectY = 1000, 2500
- initial speedX and speedY = -500, 1000
- targetX, targetY = 8000, 3000
- thrustX, thrustX = targetX, targetY

[image: basic trajectory]

[image]

This table use these formulas:

- objectX(step) = objectX(step-1) + speedX(step)
- objectY(step) = objectY(step-1) + speedY(step)
- speedX(step) = speedX(step-1)*0.9 + thrustX(step-1)
- speedY(step) = speedY(step-1)*0.9 + thrustY(step-1)
- angle(step) = degrees(atan2(targetX(step) - objectX(step); targetY(step) - objectY(step)))
- thrustX(step) = cos(radians(angle(step))) * thrust(step)
- thrustY(step) = sin(radians(angle(step))) * thrust(step)

I want to find the algorithm that would make me get directly to the target rather than turn around

Comment: How thrustValue and thrust destination influences on the object?

Comment: thrust on X is added to speedX and thrust on Y is added to speedY

Comment: Is TrustX acceleration acting in the same direction all the time? Give more details.

Comment: I'll edit post: thrust can be negative (from -100 to 100)

Comment: Does the object have a mass ? Do you know it? Is it constant?

Comment: No mass but friction : each turns speed decrease by 10% before applying thrust

Comment: So speed is like _position change per tick_ ? Does the thrust stop to accelerate/decelerate the object at some point?

Comment: Now friction arises... Do you believe in telepathy?

Comment: Yes, speed is like position change per tick. Firstly I have to use positive thrust to accelerate towards the target. A complicated point is to know from when I have to apply a negative thrust

Comment: OK, I understand some questions now, I forgot a note about 'friction' in the subject: each steps (ticks), previous speed vector is multiplied by 0.9 before applying thrust